# java overriding static fields

Tags: java, inheritance, static, overriding

```
public class A {
       public String s="A";
       public static int i=1;
   }
public class B extends A {
      public String s="B";
      public static int i=2;
public static void main(String [] args) {
              A a= new B();
              B b= new B();
              System.out.print(a.s+a.i);
              System.out.print(b.s+b.i);
}
}
```

Why the output is "A1B2" instead of "A1B1"? Doesn't fields can't be overridden, and also static fields can't?

Comment: You're not overriding anything -- you're **hiding** fields.

Comment: Does "hiding" can be done with the static field?

Comment: What is the difference between hiding and overriding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're confused with the concept of Overriding.

in Java, as far as class variables are concerned, you do not override them, you hide them.

> **Overriding is for instance methods. Hiding is for instance variables.**

Both Hiding and Overriding are different.

Comment: +1 just because this answer is totally correct and probably only was voted -1 by the question author, because he didn't understand or want to hear the answer...